# AutoMapper's Ignore() not working?

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I'm trying to ignore a property from my type when performing mapping using AutoMapper. I define mapping this way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TypeA, TypeA>().ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Both source and destination are the same types. 
When I call Map function, destination's Id property gets updated anyway.
I'm using the latest version downloaded from CodePlex.

Comment: can you post the code to you `Map` function call? I just threw together an equivalent example and it worked. What is the Id getting initialized to?

Comment: This functionality has been working for me as well. Please post a failing example so we can try it.

Comment: Also, how are you executing the map -- is Automapper creating the destination or are you providing an existing destination?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was my stupid fault. That's why one should not work at 4 am :(

Comment: You should really include the fix, no matter how stupid. I'm having this same issue, and I could very well be making the same "stupid" mistake! hah

Comment: Or, as the post is right now, rather delete it.