# AutoMapper's Ignore() not working when using ForSourceMember?

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, automapper-3

I'm trying to ignore a property from source type. I have defined mapping like this:

```
var map = AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Article, IArticle>();
map.ForSourceMember(s => s.DateCreated, opt => opt.Ignore());
map.ForSourceMember(s => s.DateUpdated, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

When I call Map function,

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(article, articlePoco);
```

destination's properties gets updated anyway. I'm using the latest stable version downloaded from NuGet.

Any ideas why this isn't working ?

I have found similar question to this one but there is no answer attached. [question]:[AutoMapper's Ignore() not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492567/automappers-ignore-not-working)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the mapping to use ForMember:

```
map.ForMember(s => s.DateCreated, opt => opt.Ignore());
map.ForMember(s => s.DateUpdated, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick, but for me it's a bit strange to set the ignore on destination member when doing the mapping because I'm actually ignoring the data in the source not the destination.

Comment: I made the same mistake too. I blame AutoMapper's documentation. It's not written for beginners that's for sure. Somehow after reading the wiki and googling, I couldn't get a definitive answer. Until now.

Comment: This should not be marked as the answer:

SourceDto.Foo

DestiationDto //Foo not a member!!!

Answer (score 11):

If the property that you want to ignore only exists in the source object then you can you `MemberList.Source` in combination with the option method `DoNotValidate()`. See below:

```
CreateMap<IArticle, Article>(MemberList.Source)
    map.ForSourceMember(src => src.DateCreated, opt=> opt.DoNotValidate());
    map.ForSourceMember(src => src.DateUpdated, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());
```

This is perfect if you are using `AssertConfigurationIsValid` and want to ignore validation of certain source properties.

Comment: What is "MemberList.Source" and where did you get it?  Also, check your code.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier See the official documentation: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html#selecting-members-to-validate