# AutoMapper ForMember not working when using ignore properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using auto mapper to map two objects, but when I call

```
Mapper.Map<PropertyDto>(CreatePropertyRequestDto, property)
```

an exception is thrown saying

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>   ==================================================================================================================================== AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be
>   mapped using the current configuration. CreatePropertyRequestDto ->
>   PropertyDto (Destination member list)
>   PropertyHippo.Properties.Shared.HttpRequestResponse.Dto.CreatePropertyRequestDto
>   -> PropertyHippo.Properties.Shared.Dto.PropertyDto (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: PropertyId Guid CreateDate UpdateDate
>   LastEditedBy GuidString

Below is my configuration.

```
    CreateMap<CreatePropertyRequestDto, PropertyDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyId, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Guid, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.CreateDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdateDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.LastEditedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.GuidString, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I have searched for the answer and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784612/automapper-formember-ignore-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267098/automappers-ignore-not-working-when-using-forsourcemember) and [in the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html?highlight=ignore#overriding-configuration-errors) but I still can't see what I'm doing wrong.

What am I missing?

EDIT

Added the breakpoint and can see that block of code is being hit. As a test I also removed the offending properties and can see the mapping works as expected

Comment: Please edit your question to include a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Progman thank you for the suggestion to create an MCVE. While creating an MCVE I had a problem initalising the mapper and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284349/automapper-error-saying-mapper-not-initialized).

My problem was that I was using a static method Mapper.Map and I should have been injecting a type of IMapper (while writing this answer I see that my question missed how the mapperConfigurations were being set).

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperConfig());
            cfg.AddProfile(new SqlAutoMapperConfig());
        });

        services.AddSingleton(config.CreateMapper());

        services.AddMvc();

        _container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        _container.Register<IMapper>(() => mapperConfig.CreateMapper(_container.GetInstance));
    }
```

Handler.cs

```
public class PropertyRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<NewPropertyRequest, string>
    {
        public PropertyRequestHandler(IPropertyManager propertyManager, IMapper mapper)
        {
            Ensure.That(mapper).IsNotNull();

            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        private IMapper _mapper { get; }

        public string Handle(NewPropertyRequest message)
        {
            var newProperty = _mapper.Map<PropertyDto>(message.NewProperty);
            ...other stuff...
        }
    }
```